# Intuition behind factor ring, ideals with multiple generators and isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, intuition

Given the following statement:

$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(1-x,n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How would one go around wrapping their head around it?

For instance, when dealing with factor rings like $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ everything is of the form $a+bX$ and then you can apply the "think-of-generator-as-zero" trick and obtain $X^2=-1$ and see how it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

But what happens when you factor a ring by an ideal generated by two elements? What's the form of the elements inside $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(1-x,n)$?

Comment: Actually this is true for all integers $p$, not only for primes.

Comment: Thank you, edited accordingly.

Comment: When factoring out an ideal generated by two elements, you can instead factor out first by the ideal generated by one element and then by the image of the ideal generated by the other in this new quotient. In the present case, either order will make it easy to see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

The isomorphism works for  *any* $n$, and is true because of the *3rd isomorphism theorem*:
$$\mathbf Z[X]/(np,1-X)\simeq (\mathbf Z[X]/n\mathbf Z[X])/\bigl((n,1-X)/p\mathbf Z[X]\bigr)$$
and of this isomorphism: $\;\mathbf Z[X]/n\mathbf Z[X]\simeq (\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)[X]$.

In practice,  a polynomial $f(X)$ modulo $(n, 1-X)$ is the same as$\bar f(\bar1)$ where $\bar f$ is the polynomial with coefficients reduced modulo $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the intuition is pretty much the same, you want morphism $\varphi:\Bbb Z[x]\to \Bbb Z_p$ such that $1-x$ and $p$ map to $0$, i.e. $\varphi(x) = \varphi(1)$, $\varphi(p) = p\varphi(1) = 0$. Reasoning is that ideal is sent to $0$ if and only if its generators are. Now, if you send $1$ to $1$, you get map $$\varphi(a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n) = a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n.$$ This is obviously surjective map, all it now needs to be shown is $\ker \varphi = (1-x,p)$ to establish the requested isomorphism. Now, if $f\in\ker\varphi$, then the sum of it's coefficients is divisible by $p$. Let $\{a_{i_1},\ldots a_{i_k}\}$ be all coefficients of $f$ divisible by $p$ and $\{b_{j_1}\,\ldots, b_{j_l}\}$ those that are not. Now, $$f=\sum_r a_{i_r}x^{i_r} + \sum_r b_{j_r}x^{j_r}$$ where the left sum is divisible by $p$, and the right has $1$ as its root, hence is divisible by $1-x$. We conclude that $f = g(x)(1-x)+h(x)p$ and thus $f\in (1-x,p)$ completing the proof.

As you can see, $p$ being prime had absolutely no role, except that for $p$ prime you can conclude that $(1-x,p)$ is maximal ideal. If $p$ weren't prime, $\Bbb Z_p$ would not be integral domain and $(1-x,p)$ wouldn't be prime ideal.

Comment: Why is it necessary for $f$'s coefficient sum to be divisible by $p$ in order to be in $\ker \varphi$?(Second paragraph)

Comment: @AlexB., observe the definition of $\varphi$. $\varphi f = 0$ implies that sum of coefficients of $f$ is $0$ in $\Bbb Z_p$, and that is the case precisely if $p$ divides it (in $\Bbb Z$, that is).